# Getting error to connecting power apps on Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, authentication, powerapp

I am trying to create a PowerApp using SharePoint online list.

But getting below error related to authentication:

[image]

Comment: Is this the first time you use PowerApps or it just appears suddenly? Which Office 365 plan are you using?

Comment: yes my friend using first time on this office 365 tenet

Comment: So I assume that you have purchased or started trial for PowerApps plan? Have you assigned the user license via Microsoft 365 admin center > Active users > user > Licenses and Apps?

Comment: Yes, I have assigned PowerApps license to the user facing this issue.